# Вопрос по работе с раббитом. pika.exceptions.ConnectionWrongStateError: Illegal close(320, "Timeout while setting up AMQP

Tags: python, асинхронность, asyncio, rabbitmq

Есть задача, асинхронно закинуть сообщения в очередь раббита. Делаю я это следующим образом:

```
import pika
import datetime
import traceback
import asyncio
import argparse
import os
import jsonschema
import json
from pika.adapters.asyncio_connection import AsyncioConnection


class MQHandler:
    def __init__(self, mq_name, mq_user, mq_password, mq_host, mq_vhost, ioloop):
        self.mq_name = mq_name
        self.mq_user = mq_user
        self.mq_password = mq_password
        self.mq_host = mq_host
        self.mq_vhost = mq_vhost
        self.ioloop = ioloop
        self.user_params = pika.PlainCredentials(username=mq_user, password=mq_password)
        self.connection_params = pika.ConnectionParameters(host=mq_host, virtual_host=mq_vhost, credentials=self.user_params)

    async def process(self, message_list):
        self.connection()
        while not hasattr(self, 'channel'):
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
        for message in message_list:
            self.basic_publish(message)

    def connection(self):
        self.connect = AsyncioConnection(parameters=self.connection_params,
                                         custom_ioloop=self.ioloop,
                                         on_open_callback=self.on_connection_open,
                                         on_open_error_callback=self.on_connection_open_error,
                                         on_close_callback=self.on_close_callback)

    def on_connection_open(self):
        print('connection open')
        self.connect.channel(on_open_callback=self.on_channel_open)

    def on_channel_open(self, channel):
        print(datetime.datetime.now(), 'channel open')
        self.channel = channel
        self.channel.queue_declare(self.mq_name)
        self.channel.add_on_close_callback(self.on_channel_closed)

    def on_connection_open_error(self, connection, error):
        print(datetime.datetime.now(), "on connection {} error: {} state: {}".format(connection, error, connection.is_open))
        self.connection()

    def on_close_callback(self, connection, reason):
        print(datetime.datetime.now(), 'connection closed')

    def on_channel_closed(self, channel, reason):
        print(datetime.datetime.now(), 'channel closed, reason: {}'.format(reason))
        try:
            self.connect.close()
        except:
            print(datetime.datetime.now(), traceback.format_exc())

    def basic_publish(self, message):
        self.channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key=self.mq_name, body=message)


class TaskRunner:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.task_list = []

    def add_task(self, task, *args):
        self.task_list.append((task, args))

    def start(self):
        if self.ioloop is None:
            raise Exception("Can't create ioloop")
        try:
            for task in self.task_list:
                self.ioloop.create_task(task[0].process(*task[1]))
            self.ioloop.run_forever()
        finally:
            self.ioloop.close()


arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
arg_parser.add_argument('properties', help="path to properties file")
arg_parser.add_argument('schema_properties', help="path to schema properties file")
parsed_args = arg_parser.parse_args()
params_path = parsed_args.properties
schema_path = parsed_args.schema_properties

if os.path.isfile(params_path) and os.path.isfile(schema_path):
    with open(params_path) as f:
        properties = json.load(f)
    with open(schema_path) as f:
        schema = json.load(f)
    jsonschema.validate(properties, schema)
    mq_params = properties["rabbit_params"]
    message = 'Hello!'
    task_runner = TaskRunner()
    mq_handler = MQHandler(mq_params['filename_query'],
                           mq_params['user'],
                           mq_params['password'],
                           mq_params['host'],
                           mq_params['vhost'],
                           task_runner.ioloop)
    message_list = [message]
    task_runner.add_task(mq_handler, message_list)
    task_runner.start()
```

Где, params_path - путь к конфигу(JSON с параметрами для запуска), schema_path путь к схеме для конфига(JSON). Проблема в том, что при запуске почему-то закрывается соединение. 
Вот, что выводится в консоль:

```
2019-09-24 08:35:50.680989 connection closed
Exception in callback AMQPConnector._on_overall_timeout()
handle: <TimerHandle when=37623.892 AMQPConnector._on_overall_timeout()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 88, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\utils\connection_workflow.py", line 341, in _on_overall_timeout
    self._amqp_conn.close(320, msg)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pika\connection.py", line 1283, in close
    raise exceptions.ConnectionWrongStateError(msg)
pika.exceptions.ConnectionWrongStateError: Illegal close(320, "Timeout while setting up AMQP to '172.23.16.18'/(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>, 6, '', ('172.23.16.18', 5672)); ssl=False") request on <AsyncioConnection CLOSED transport=None params=<ConnectionParameters host=172.23.16.18 port=5672 virtual_host=run ssl=False>> because it was called while connection state=CLOSED.
```

Вопрос: почему закрывается соединение? Что я делаю не так? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что при подключении происходит exception, которую Вы не видите из за того, что код асинхронный.

В Вашем случае, `on_open_callback` должен иметь один параметр—connection. Вы же указали метод, `on_connection_open`, у которого нет параметров.

Если хотите видеть в консоле разные exception, которые происходят при подключении, добавьте следующий код перед подключением:

```
logging.basicConfig()
```